# SAT question: “pass on a trait” vs “inherit a trait”

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I'm so confused about this... please help me.

This is a sentence correction question from the SAT:

> Giraffes born with very long necks were able to stay alive when food was scarce, __________________.

Which phrase best completes the sentence?

> A. and were therefore able to pass this desirable trait on to their offspring
>
> B. and this desirable trait was passed on as a result to its offspring
>
> C. so that their offspring could have this desirable trait passed to them
>
> D. so, therefore, this desirable trait would be inherited by their offspring
>
> E. and therefore have this desirable trait inherited in their offspring

The answer is A, but I don't understand why C, E and B are wrong?

Comment: **C** implies that the giraffes stayed alive for the purpose of passing the trait to their offspring; maybe true from some biological standpoint, but probably not what the giraffes were consciously doing. **E** uses the present tense instead of the past tense. **B** should use "their" instead of "its", since the subject is not a single giraffe. I hope this helps!

Comment: @Vance Post it!

Comment: Heh, I guess that would be sensible to do! I hadn't quite twigged on the problem with B at first, so I was just going to leave C and E in the comment.

Comment: @Vance: is that really what's wrong with E? The *have* could be part of *were able to have*, where one can remove the repeated *were able to* by the rules for elision. Another thing that might be wrong with E is *"inherited in"* rather than *"inherited by"*.

Answer (score 2):

**C** implies that the giraffes stayed alive for the purpose of passing the trait to their offspring; maybe true from some biological standpoint, but probably not what the giraffes were consciously doing.

**E** uses the present tense instead of the past tense.

**B** should use "their" instead of "its", since the subject is not a single giraffe.